# OnItemClickLictener

Tags: android, listview

Долго искал, но так и не нашел. Не могу разобраться, как сделать.
Необходимо из списка (ListView 3 пункта) при переходе из каждого, открывать новую активити. На данный момент открывается только список и все. Получалось открывать активити, но на всех трех пунктах открывается одна и та же, но и этот метод я забыл как делал (Сильно не ругайте, начинающий только. Помогите кусочком кода, который обрабатывает нажатия на пункты ListView).

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


final String[] radioNames = new String[]{"deep", "progressive", "dutch"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, radioNames
    );
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

    switch (getListView().getId()) {
        case R.id.listDeep:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeepActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}
```

}

Comment: Вам надо через интент передать список с данными + позицию в списке для получения нужных данных, либо передайте только нужные данные. Далее в запущенной активити вытащите эти данные из интента

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрите часть моего кода. Что не так я делаю?

Comment: У вас нет в коде попытки передать данные с интенетом. Также возможно надо назначить слушатель нажатий для списка. Вообще никто не использует такую активити